# lubridate mdy format issue

Tags: r, lubridate

I have a `date` column whose date values are something like this:

```
date = c("1/6/2022", "1/6/2022", "1/19/2022", "1/20/2022")
```

When I try to convert it to new date column using `lubridate::mdy` I get:

```
library(lubridate)

date_new = lubridate::mdy(date)

print(date_new)

[1] "2022-01-06" "2022-01-06" "2022-01-19" "2022-01-20"

# Desired output (mm-dd-yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy): 
[1] "01-06-2022" "01-06-2022" "01-19-2022" "01-20-2022"
```

How can I get the desired output using `lubridate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `format`

```
format(lubridate::mdy(date), '%m-%d-%Y')
[1] "01-06-2022" "01-06-2022" "01-19-2022" "01-20-2022"
```

Comment: Yes sorry that comment was by mistake

Comment: @Ed_Gravy as you don't really need Date class, you may also do `gsub("\\b(\\d)-", "0\\1-", chartr('/', '-', date))#[1] "01-06-2022" "01-06-2022" "01-19-2022" "01-20-2022"`

Comment: Thank you sir, yes I just want a date column that `MS-Excel` picks up as a date. Because, I have to then import the Excel file as a list to a `SharePoint website`. And `SharePoint` is `very sensitive` to `incorrect dates`, if it sees even one wrong date value in a column, SharePoint converts the whole column to `text` and thus the dates get converted to `numeric values`. That's why I have been asking all these questions related to `dates` lately.

Comment: @Ed_Gravy got it.  Probably, it checks the width of the column along with format